# Retrieve values from data structure holding variant data types without specifying the return type

Tags: c++, boost

I am currently using a map with string data type as key and a variant value. I am relying on the boost::variant library for defining the map data type. I am currently following a few tutorial on boost::variant for extracting the values from the map without having to specifying the exact data type value I want to retrieve while iterating through it.
source: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.variant
I want something like the last example for generic data type but instead of printing the values I was to return them.
The following below does not seem to be working correctly.

```
struct output : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
  template <typename T>
  T operator()(T t) const { return t }
};
```

I also instantiate a map while populating it with a string data type as keys and boost::variant type as values; and later on iterate through the map and process the values.

```
std::map<std::string,boost::variant<int, double, long long, std::string>> _keyPairValue;

for(auto &x: _keyPairValue)
{
  // appending a key pair value to a bson object which is part of mongo sdk
  b << x.first << boost::apply_visitor(output{},x.second);
}
```

Comment: Please expand on _"...does not seem to be working correctly..."_ so we know what the problem is.

Comment: Small note: From C++17 onwards, you should also be able to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? I find the question rather difficult to understand...

Answer (score 1):

> I want something like the last example for generic data type but instead of printing the values I was to return them.

You probably want to have `operator()` overloads, something like:

```
struct process : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
  void operator()(double d)
  {
      // process d ...
  }
  void operator()(char c)
  {
       // process c ...
  }
  void operator()(const string& s)
  {
      // process s ...
  }
};

int main()
{
  boost::variant<double, char, std::string> v;
  v = 3.14;
  boost::apply_visitor(process{}, v);
  v = 'A';
  boost::apply_visitor(process{}, v);
  v = "Boost";
  boost::apply_visitor(process{}, v);
}
```